# Downloading file from a datatable and pdf graph with 2 download buttons

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dt

I need to export the graph and the xls from 2 SQL queries
My graph is linked with the datatable by clicking on a row
I placed the 2 download buttons but I don't know how to trig the exports with buttons (maybe with another reactive function ?)

Thank you for your help

Here my UI.R :

```
mainPanel(
DT::dataTableOutput("table"), #My Table 
plotOutput("plot")) # My graph
downloadButton("plot_export", "PDF"),
                         # Button
downloadButton("downloadData", "XLS")
 ))
```

Here the server.R :

```
 cpk_total <- reactive({
 data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

 SQL query to feed my dataTable 

 Close connexion data_testeur

 return result created from the SQL query
})

 output$Table <- DT::renderDataTable({
 DT::datatable(cpk_total(),...) # Formating table
  })

output$plot <- renderPlot({
dta <- cpk_total()
data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

  another SQL query to trace the graph for 1 item selected
  #This SQL query use a variable from the created cpk_total table

 Close connexion data_testeur

 graph <- ....

   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add some thing like this for the table

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler (
  filename = function() {
    #some function to generate your file name
    },
  content = function(file) {
    dta <- cpk_total()
    write.csv2(dta, file, row.names = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8", quote = FALSE, na = "")
  }  
)
```

and for the chart I would pull the code out from the `renderPlot` into a seperate `reactive` just like you have done with `cpk_total()`

and the add something like this for the download of the plot

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler (
  filename = function() {
    #some function to generate your file name
    },
  content = function(file) {
    p <- reactive_plot()
    export(p, file = file)
  }  
)
```

Comment: Hi Bertil - Thanks again for your answer - It works fine and I just replace the export function by a ggsave -